# apt-get install -f wants to remove linux-image-generic

Tags: apt

I seem to remember doing the suggested `autoremove` earlier this year and bricking my system in the process. `linux-headers-generic` and `linux-image-generic` seem pretty important.

```
    phm@LuckyCompCo:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
      libmono-accessibility4.0-cil
      libmono-system-runtime-serialization-formatters-soap4.0-cil
      libmono-system-windows-forms4.0-cil libmono-webbrowser4.0-cil
      linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic
    Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
    0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 14 not upgraded.
```

Comment: For 2, see http://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those package are being suggested to be removed because they are marked as "Automatically installed" instead of manually:

> The following packages **were automatically installed** and are no longer required:

This *is not normally the case* as Ubuntu tries to keep the system using the latest available kernel using this metapackage, in fact, after you install your system most packages are marked as manually installed. You unknowingly must have set it up as automatically installed, but you can safely ignore the message so long you don't use the `autoremove` command. To mark those packages as manually installed you can use `apt-mark`:

```
sudo apt-mark manual linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic
```

With this, the package must be successfully removed from the list. You can use `aptitude`'s `unmarkauto` to mark packages as manually installed too.

---

Why not using `apt-get install packages` to mark them?

First of all, it can get undesired results such as upgrading the packages or install others unrelated packages. Secondly, that's not the usage of the `install` command. This *feature* was implemented so when you select to install a package already installed it wouldn't be uninstalled automatically when you used `autoremove` or with other packages, since you already listed the package to be installed explicitly, instead of implicitly as result of other package installation.

Answer (score 5):

The two packages `linux-headers-generic` and `linux-image-generic` are meta-packages. They provide nothing by themselves, but rely on other packages. These two always depend on the latest version of the kernel, so when you do `apt-get upgrade`, the latest version get installed. You can safely remove them, but you won't be prompted for kernel upgrades if you do. You can mark them as manually installed:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic
```

After this, `autoremove` should not suggest removing these two.